# Ontology-based content management system/development framework

Tags: sql, xml, wordpress, content-management-system, rdf

I'm seeking a content management system or development framework that will allow me to add a semantic metadata layer (via inline markup) to website content (paragraph text and images), allowing me to create an interface for users through which they can "create their own report" via a basic search/filter from. The whole 110 page report will be available as static HTML content, but when the user selects a few basic parameters in the search/filter form, the report only presents the chunks of content that are marked by metadata associated with their query/settings. From my research, I know that these systems are sometimes called Ontology-based Content Management Systems or semantic website content search.

Ideally, it would be an open source or paid solution that would deliver roughly the same functionality as OntoText's Open Policy: http://www.ontotext.com/government

Comment: Why did you use the tags [tag:sql], [tag:rdf], [tag:wordpress] and [tag:xml]? Are these requirements?

Comment: If you've already found Ontotext's Open Policy as being "roughly the same functionality" , why isn't that good enough?

More generally speaking, this appears off-topic for Stackoverflow, according to its [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), since you're effectively asking for a tool recommendation.